# how to submit form and add a row in DB

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am having problem with this javascript function.

If I want to submit a form if I do this below it works:

```
function submitform()
{
    var QandAO = document.getElementById("QandA");
    QandAO.submit();
}
```

If I want to add a row into a DB table using AJAX to navigate to the page which INSERTS VALUES, then the code below works:

```
function submitform()
{
    var fieldvalue = $("#QandA").val();
    $.post("insertQuestion.php", $("#QandA").serialize ,function(data){
        alert("data");
    });
}
```

So I thought to be able to submit the form and add a row into the database, if I do this code below then it should work but it doesn't. It submits the form but does not add a row in the database. How can this code be fixed so it submits the form and also add a row in DB? Below is the code

```
function submitform()
{
    var fieldvalue = $("#QandA").val();
    $.post("insertQuestion.php", $("#QandA").serialize ,function(data){
        alert("data");
    });   
    var QandAO = document.getElementById("QandA");
    QandAO.submit();
}
```

InsertQuestion.php looks like this below:

```
<?php
session_start();

$username="xxx";
$password="xxx";
$database="xxx";

mysql_connect('localhost',$username,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

$insertquestion = array();
$insertquestion[] = "' ". mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['id'] ) . "'";

$questionsql = "INSERT INTO Question (SessionId) 
VALUES (" . implode('), (', $insertquestion) . ")";

mysql_query($questionsql);
mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: what does insertQuestion.php look like?

Comment: Learn to debug properly.  Chrome Developer Tools and Firebug are your friends.  You can see JS errors and network requests then, and you can figure out specifically where the failure is occuring.  Also, $("#QandA").serialize should be $("#QandA").serialize().

Comment: added insertQuestion.php into question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that the second part of your code (the form submit) cuts off the first part before it's complete.  Give the AJAX call a chance to finish by putting the form submit inside the AJAX callback:

```
function submitform()
{
    var fieldvalue = $("#QandA").val();
    $.post("insertQuestion.php", $("#QandA").serialize ,function(data){
        alert("data");
        var QandAO = document.getElementById("QandA");
        QandAO.submit();
    });   
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that has submitted the form and add the row. Thanks :)